# ¿Deseo realizar un calculo matemático en react js con datos de una base de datos y datos del front, como puedo hacerlo,

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, mongodb

Tengo en mi frontend, el componente donde esta el formulario y los inputs

```
import React from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

export const Ponderados = () => {


  return (
    
    
    <>
    <p className="ponderado__caution"> <b>IMPORTANTE:</b> Los resultados obtenidos en este ponderado <b>NO TIENEN RELACIÓN</b> con los procesos de admisión y <b>NO ASEGURAN </b>el ingreso al programa que se desea. Este aplicativo es única y exclusivamente una <b>HERRAMIENTA DE ORIENTACIÓN</b> y es autonomía de la persona utilizarlo. </p>
        <div className='ponderado__contenedor'>
          <div className='ponderado_contenedor-sidebar'>
            <div className='mt-5'>
            <button className='btn-small'> Instrucciones</button>
            </div>
            <div className='mt-5'>
            <button className='btn-small'> Encuesta </button>
            </div>
            <div className='mt-5'>
            <button className='btn-small'> Puntajes de cierre </button>
            </div>

          </div>

          <div className='ponderado__contenedor-principal'>
              <form className='ponderado__form-pd'>
                <input 
                type="text"
                placeholder="Lectura Crítica"
                name="lc"
                className="ponderado__input"
                autoComplete='off'
                />

                <input 
                type="text"
                placeholder="Matemáticas"
                name="mt"
                className="ponderado__input"
                autoComplete='off'
                />

                <input 
                type="text"
                placeholder="Sociales y Ciudadanas"
                name="sc"
                className="ponderado__input"
                autoComplete='off'
                />

                <input 
                type="text"
                placeholder="Ciencias Naturales"
                name="cs"
                className="ponderado__input"
                autoComplete='off'
                />

                <input 
                type="text"
                placeholder="Inglés"
                name="ing"
                className="ponderado__input"
                autoComplete='off'
                />

                <button 
                  type="submit"
                  className="btn btn-primary btn-medium mt-5"
                >
                  <i className="fa-solid fa-chart-column st"></i>
                  Realizar ponderado ICFES
                </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Lo que quiero saber es como tomar los datos de los inputs y tomar los datos de mi backend

Este es el modelo que establecí y que tengo almacenados en MongoDB

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const careerSchema = new Schema(
    {
        name: {type:String},
        lc: {type:Number},
        cn: {type:Number},
        cs: {type:Number},
        mt: {type:Number},
        in: {type:Number}
    },
    {collection:'facultad_economia'}
)

export default mongoose.model('BlogModel', careerSchema)
```

Lo que quiero es crear el metodo, para al hacer el submit en el boton del frontend y que me realice el calculo, que en funcion logica sería,

Tomar los datos del back, que son tipo números ejemplo de calculo

### Datos ingresados en el front

### Lectura critica: 60
Matematicas: 67
Sociales y ciudadanas: 64
Ciencias naturales: 62
Ingles: 70

así mismo del back habrá un numero por cada dato ingresado, ejemplo para lectura critica 0.46, matematicas 0.25, y así hasta sumar 100

El calculo final sera,

tomar los datos del front multiplicarlos por los del back y sumarlos
(60x0.46)+(67x0.25)+...(70x0.10)= 65---> que es el calculo final que deseo obtener

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No entiendo el problema.. pasas los datos a alguno de los dos lados, y haces el calculo... cual es la pregunta?

Comment: Te recomiendo que leas [example]